# Probability distributions in an ordered set of random extracted elements

Tags: probability, distributions

I tried looking for an existing solution for the following problem:

- Assume that S is a set of d elements, and R is a total order relation on S. Assume that n elements are randomly extracted from S, and then they are ordered according to R. Which is the probability that in the i-th position of the ordered set of n elements there is the x-th element of S? (where the x-th element of S is intended according to the R). In other words, which is the probability distribution function for the i-th position of the ordered set of n elements?

Do you know if such a problem has already been solved? I have not found any specific solution in the literature or elsewhere. I tried to find my own solution, but I would like to know if something already exists.

Comment: Perhaps, see Wikipedia on [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic). Second section.

Comment: Thanks @BruceET, I found what I needed.

Comment: Solved! Thanks to BruceET's suggestion.

Comment: @Pierangelo You could write an answer explaining in detail what about Bruce's suggestion solved your problem, and how to apply the wikipedia page about order statistics to address your question.

Comment: Most welcome; glad you got it.